# How to Open Attachments of blob content in Cordova iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ipad

I am using the below code to get the attachments content and creating a blob to open the attachments. The content is fetched successfully and blob is also created, but the attachment is not opening though it works in chrome as web app but not in Cordova iOs APP.

Is there something to be added in addition.

```
{
var details =
    "Username=username&Password=Password";
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", url, true,
    "username",
    "password");
http.setRequestHeader(
    "Content-type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
);
http.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
    if (http.readyState == 4 &&
        http.status == 200) {
        var ticket = JSON.parse(
            http.responseText
        ).ticket;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET',
            "http://hostname/url",
            true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader(
            "header",
            ticket);
        xhr.responseType =
            'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (this.status ===
                200) {
                var blob =
                    new Blob(
                        [
                            xhr
                            .response
                        ], {
                            type: "application/pdf"
                        });
                var
                    objectUrl =
                    URL.createObjectURL(
                        blob
                    );
                window.open(
                    objectUrl
                ); // blob:file:///835fce36-9a25-4dbb-9e16-d3fcb9d27fef"
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
}
http.send(details);
```

}

```
Error : [Error] url ->file:///1811f4d5-17f0-4124-a761-70a4b4d9f361
(anonymous function) (console-via-logger.js:173)
(anonymous function) (logger.js:754)
(anonymous function) (attachmentviewer.js:80)
(anonymous function) (i18n.js:55)
callbackFromNative (cordova.js:293)
nc2 (cordova.js:1022)
[Error] current window.location -
>file:///Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D2891D9A-
E669-4F16-849E-
D63532979F00/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0A917ACE-
9F1B-42B8-B745-C351BAA3A369/Equip%20R2.0.app/www/index.html#/Attachment/30
(anonymous function) (console-via-logger.js:173)
(anonymous function) (logger.js:754)
(anonymous function) (attachmentviewer.js:81)
(anonymous function) (i18n.js:55)
callbackFromNative (cordova.js:293)
nc2 (cordova.js:1022)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the InApp browser has worked.
InApp Browser : [Link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/)

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(objectUrl, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```