# Cordova fileWriter.write() doesn't work with blobs

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, blob, cordova-plugins

In the official documentation and many other solutions posted online, the following code is supposed to be the way of writing data to a file in Cordova

```
function writeFile(fileEntry, dataObj) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
        fileWriter.write(dataObj);
    });
}

writeFile(someFileEntry, blob);
```

In the documentation, they explicitly shown that a blob can be passed as the "dataObj", but whenever I passed a blob as "dataObj", the resulting file only has 2 bytes of data. After inspecting the file, I found that the contents of the file only contain a single string

```
{}
```

hence the 2 bytes.

I've tried passing a string as the "dataObj", and the contents of the resulting file was the exact same string, so string works I guess? But the data I'm wishing to write to a file is a blob that contains video data recorded from a canvas, so either I'll have to

1. somehow convert the the video blob into a string and write the string into the file
2. somehow fix the "fileWriter.write" function

But I've gone nowhere with these solutions. I've tried "blob.text()" or using a "fileReader" to get the contents of the blob as a string, but the resulting file is always broken. And fixing the "fileWriter.write" function is way out of my depth. Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Open Attachments of blob content in Cordova iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43110114/how-to-open-attachments-of-blob-content-in-cordova-ios-app)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I think it might have something to do with the following as stated on the cordova-plugin-file docs:
[image]

But I find that odd since the examples all use FileWriter.write(blob) but it says that the platforms do not support that function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hmm... well the only option left seems to be writing the blob into the file as text, but so far all my attempts of doing so have resulted in a corrupted file. Do you have any knowledge on how this could be done correctly? (The blob in question is video data recorded from a canvas)